# Why do I get an array IndexOutOfBounds error?

Tags: java, arrays

I got a java book and am doing some exercises about Arrays. Could anyone help me understand why this is out of bounds?
The exercise is to create 3 classes: a CollegeCourse; a Student and a InputGrades with the main method. When I run it, it goes fine until it shows my array is out of bounds. It crashes when I'm about to enter the second course for the third student.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String info = null;
    int infoInt = 0;
    char infoChar = 0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    CollegeCourse[] courses = new CollegeCourse[2];
    for(int i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
        courses[i] = new CollegeCourse();
    }

    Student[] students = new Student[3];
    for(int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
        students[i] = new Student();
    }
    System.out.println("Welcome to Java Programming.\n   Professor, enter your students' info below.");
    for(int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("\nEnter student ID >>> ");
        infoInt = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        students[i].setStudentID(infoInt);

        for(int j = 0; j < courses.length; j++) {
            System.out.print("Enter course ID >>> ");
            info = input.nextLine();
            courses[j].setCourseID(info);

            System.out.print("Enter credit hours >>> ");
            infoInt = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine();
            courses[j].setCreditHours(infoInt);

            System.out.print("Enter letter grade >>> ");
            info = input.nextLine();
            info = info.toUpperCase();
            info.toCharArray();
            infoChar = info.charAt(0);
            courses[i].setLetterGrade(infoChar);
        }
    }
}
```

My output is:

```
Welcome to Java Programming.
  Professor, enter your students' info below.

Enter student ID >>> 1468
Enter course ID >>> cis 210
Enter credit hours >>> 3
Enter letter grade >>> b
Enter course ID >>> smm 310
Enter credit hours >>> 5
Enter letter grade >>> a

Enter student ID >>> 1449
Enter course ID >>> cis 210
Enter credit hours >>> 5
Enter letter grade >>> a
Enter course ID >>> smm 310
Enter credit hours >>> 5
Enter letter grade >>> a

Enter student ID >>> 1986
Enter course ID >>> cis 210
Enter credit hours >>> 2
Enter letter grade >>> c
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
   at Chapter08Arrays.InputGrades.main(InputGrades.java:48)
```

Comment: This code also throws an `InputMismatchException` at runtime.

Comment: definition of class Student and CollegeCourse  should be given

Comment: @MaheshKshirsagar I don't think they should be given. You can imagine what the methods on these classes are doing and it would only add unneccesary length to the question

Comment: Although you already have two current correct answers, you should have put all the code of the InputGrades class so it could be easier for us to read the line which was causing the exception. Also you could jus have figured it out using the debugger.

Answer (score 3):

Your last line shows

```
courses[i].setLetterGrade(infoChar);
```

although you're iterating through the courses with the index `j`

Changing the line to

```
courses[j].setLetterGrade(infoChar);
```

Should solve your problem

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: @KleytonSoares glad we could help

Answer (score 2):

You have problem in last line of code:

```
courses[i].setLetterGrade(infoChar);
```

Counter is `i` instead of `j`, so with correction would be:

```
courses[j].setLetterGrade(infoChar);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe I missed that.